# Can stainless steel "soap" bars actually work or is it just deceptive marketing?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, cleaning, organosulfur-compounds

The [Wikipedia — Stainless steel soap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stainless_steel_soap) article sounds highly skeptical, although it does include a possible mechanism involving the chromium in the stainless steel binding with the sulfur compounds and then being rinsed away. It seems to me that if that's what happens, you would quickly run out of chromium in the outer surface of the stainless steel, and it would no longer be effective. Seems like snake oil to me.  Has the effectiveness of the SS soap been proved from a perspective of chemistry?

Comment: Well it works ok for garlic. Have you tried it?

Comment: Did you compare it to just rinsing (without the stainless steel)?

Comment: But the real question is whether one would expect it to work based on the chemistry.

Comment: It "works ok"? What it would even supposed to do, adsorb stuff? Any real smell absorber needs to have large surface area, for starters.